# Summing terms in Table

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I have a table that looks like

```
Table[m, {k, 10}, {j, k}, {i, j}]
```

where, `m` is a square matrix that depends on the indices $i, j$, and $k$. I want to add all of the m matrices in the table. What is the most efficient way to do it?

If there are only two indices, I can do

```
Total[Apply[Join, Table[m, {k, 10}, {j, k}]]]
```

But this is not very fast.

I am trying to avoid nested sums, any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Plus@@(Table[m, {k, 10}, {j, k}, {i, j}])?

Comment: `Flatten[result,2]//Total` (result being the result of your table) should do what you're after...

Comment: Thank you both. Algohi your method does not seem to work. rasher your method works, just to be clear if I have more indices I will need to Flatten at a higher level before the Total correct? Do you have any alternative approaches to this task?

Comment: Change `Table` to `Sum`.

Comment: @user64620: Yes. I assumed you had the table and/or needed it as some intermediate result. If not, using `Sum` as commented by 2021rcampion is cleaner...

Comment: @2012rcampiom Thank you for your answers, they are very useful.

Comment: @rasher Thank you for your answers, they are very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total takes a second argument which specifies the levels to sum together. In your case you want to preserve the lowest two levels so you need to total down to level -3:

```
Total[Table[m, {k, 10}, {j, k}, {i, j}], -3]
```

This will work if you have more indices.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful.